# JDBC connection become null unexpectedly

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, db2, connection-pooling

I have a problem with database connection with JDBC(DB2). I recently implemented transaction management (commit/rollback) on a code block and I use the same connection for all my queries/operations on the database. We **never** explicitly close the connection between each query/operation. However, at runtime, we get an exception suggesting that our connection is not valid (closed/null). When I debug step-by-step, it seems like the connection fields unexpectedly becomes null. It looks random and it never happen at the same line. I'm sure that we don't close the connection ourselves! We use a connection pool in Tomcat.

Here is a code sample:

```
 try {  
 connection = DB.getConnection();
 connection.setAutoCommit(false);   
 savepoint = connection.setSavepoint("avantModif");

    /*  * Here are some queries and operations that runs without error
 when the connection is not null    */      
 connection.commit(); 

} 

catch(Exception e) {

    if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed() && savepoint != null)
      {         
           connection.rollback(savepoint);  
      }

    throw e; 
} 

finally 
{   
if(connection != null){     
    connection.close();

}
```

Here is a debugger screenshot showing Connection object content:

[image]

Here is the connection pool definition in Tomcat's server.xml:

```
  <Resource  
  name="jdbc/dbcpGlobal"
   auth="Container"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   driverClassName="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
   url="jdbc:as400://lvq400/apilib;naming=system;errors=full;date format=iso;prompt=false;trace=false;reconnect=true"
   username="[here_is_our_username]" password="[here_is_our_password]"
   maxIdle="7" maxActive="15" maxWait="5"
   removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="120" logAbandoned="true"
   testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="true" validationQuery="select 1 from sysibm/sysdummy1" />
```

The object isn't really null, its content become null!

Is there any reason that the JDBC connection content would become null?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "connection object content"? It would be much easier to help you if you'd provide a stack trace and some sample code...

Comment: You have more detail now!

Comment: Okay, thanks. Now, what does `DB.getConnection()` do? Are you using the same connection in multiple threads, perhaps?

Comment: It returns a connection from tomcat connection pool. I added the connection pool definition (in Tomcat's server.xml) in my post. The connection is not shared with other threads. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: How long are you taking to step through the code in the debugger? If it's more than 120 seconds, perhaps that's the problem... the connection pool thinks it's abandoned, and closes it.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, because the connection fields become null even if I don't debug (We log the StackTrace in the logs). I've also paused the code (using the debugger) for more than 5 minutes, and the connection was still OK after I skipped to the next line.

Comment: Ah. In that case your question is slightly misleading: "However, when I debug step-by-step, it seems like the connection fields unexpectedly becomes null" - that suggests it *only* happens when debugging, or at least that's how I read it. Probably worth updating...

Comment: Right, I've just updated my question. Do you have any other ideas why it happens? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately not - although the fact that it *doesn't* think it's closed seems odd...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're actually supposed to close the connections. Since what you get is a proxy object, "closing" it will only return it to the pool. I'm guessing Tomcat at some point starts killing off your connections as they appear abandoned. Is there anything in the log when this happens, since you have logAbandoned="true"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We made sure we logged all exceptions in Tomcat logs, and the only exception we could see was something like "Error: Connection is closed" when we tried to execute a sql query. When we stopped using transactions (commit, rollback) on the Connection object, the problem went away. We managed to manually rollback if any exception is thrown. Issue solved, but I still don't know what causes that!